# error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec when reading CSV

Tags: python-3.x

I recently download the PISA 2012 Student database from PISA. I follow the instructions and successfully read it on SAS. Then I exported as CSV to read it in Python 3, using proc export, but I keep getting this error when trying to read it in python pandas: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 24: invalid start byte. What can I do?

pisa2012_Col=pd.read_csv('Pisasubset2012Col.csv')

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
pisa2012_Col=pd.read_csv('Pisasubset2012Col.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Since `read_csv` has an encoding option to deal with files in different formats (See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings))

Comment: Why do you think that the file is encoded with ISO-8859-1?

Comment: The file is of badly encoded data for sure. And from 0xc1 in the error message, I think  `Latin_1` will do the job here. `ISO-8859-1` or `Latin_1` is of 8-bit character sets, thus all garbage has a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both. It seems to work. I read it successfully and until know, variables are responding fine to my calculations. Seems SOLVED.